# Loading Dynamic Components using ngTemplate in ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive

I am trying to set up a dynamic expansion panel like this:

```xml
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let category of categories">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        {{category.name}}
      </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <ng-template #category>
      <a>Test</a>
    </ng-template>
    <mat-action-row>
      <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="nextStep()">Next</button>
    </mat-action-row>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

and in my Component I am trying to access each of the templates like this:

```
@ViewChildren('category') components: QueryList<CategoryDirective>;
```

and

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
    const viewContainerRef = this.adHost;
    if (!_.isUndefined(this.categories) && !_.isUndefined(this.components)) {
      this.components.changes.subscribe(() => {
        this.components.toArray().forEach(el => {
            console.log('ngAfterViewInit', el);
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

For each of the categories, I have a component property which I want to load in ngTemplate.

[image]

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Since @ViewChild doesn't work because of multiple "category" directives. You can resolve this by creating a separate component for each of the items.

```
<mat-accordion>
  <ng-template ngFor let-category [ngForOf]="categories" let-i="index">
    <expansion-panel [title]="category.name" [component]="category.component" [isSelected]="category.isSelected" [index]="i"></expansion-panel>
  </ng-template>
</mat-accordion>
```

HTML:

---

```
<mat-expansion-panel [disabled]="!isSelected">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title>
      {{title}}
    </mat-panel-title>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <ng-template category></ng-template>
  <mat-action-row>
    <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="nextStep()">Next</button>
  </mat-action-row>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

and add the following in expansion-panel component.

TS:

---

```
@ViewChild(CategoryDirective) categoryDirective: CategoryDirective;
```

and

```
@Input() component: any;
```

after this you can add the component dynamically:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (!_.isUndefined(this.component)) {
      const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.component);
      const viewContainerRef = this.categoryDirective.viewContainerRef;
      console.log(viewContainerRef);
      if (!_.isUndefined(viewContainerRef)) {
        viewContainerRef.clear();

        const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
        // (<CategoryComponent>componentRef.instance).data = adItem.data;
      }
    }
  }
```